# Kotlin generateSequence in Reactor Flux

Tags: kotlin, project-reactor

Using Kotlin Sequences we're able to do something like this.

```
val seq = generateSequence(0) { it + 1 }
seq.take(4).subscripe() { println(it) }
```

This will compute a new sequence containing four values, starting with an initial value.

I am looking for a way to do achieve the same using Reactor Flux. Computing a sequence based on an initial value.
But I just found something to create a static sequence with `val f = Flux.just(0, 1, 2, ...)`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `reactor-kotlin-extensions` library to transform a Kotlin sequence into a `Flux` as simply as:

```kotlin
import reactor.kotlin.core.publisher.toFlux

// ...

generateSequence(0) { it + 1 }.toFlux().take(4).subscribe { println(it) }
```

If you want the same using Reactor only:

```kotlin
Flux.generate<Int, Int>({0}, { curr, sink -> sink.next(curr); curr + 1 })
    .take(4)
    .subscribe { println(it)}
```